# xv_11_laser_driver

Tags: ros, xv-11-laser-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has the xv_11_laser_driver been updated for fuerte?

Thanks,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50550/xv_11_laser_driver/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has never been *released* to Fuerte.

I looked around for documentation, which seems have gotten [lost on the wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/xv_11_laser_driver), probably due to recent rosdoc changes for Groovy.

I found the source code here:

```
$ roslocate info xv_11_laser_driver
- git:
    local-name: cwru-ros-pkg
    uri: http://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg.git
```

The last update in that package was a year ago. So Fuerte support looks unlikely, unless no changes were required.

It is maintained by @Chad Rockey. If you contact him, he can probably help.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0